# Harvard-style citation: "and" in running text but "&" in parentheses

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, apacite, harvard-style

By publisher requirement, when citing following the Harvard style the connector between authors needs to be "and" when in the running text, yet an ampersand "&" when in a parenthetical citation. How to achieve that?

In the current MWE the connector is "&" in both cases, but the first citation should rather appear as "Li and Wang (2020)".

**MWE:**
[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{li2020most,
    author = {Li, Ming and Wang, Qiang},
    title = {The most important paper of the century},
    journal = {Journal of Nonexistence},
    volume = {25},
    number = {4},
    pages = {250--251},
    year = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

I first cite \citet{li2020most} in the running text then cite the same paper
parenthetically \citep{li2020most}.

\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatting requirement is best handled by switching from the `natbib` citation management package to the `apacite` package (with option `natbibapa`, so that you can keep using `\citet` and `\citep`) and from the `agsm` bib style to the `apacite` bib style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{li2020most,
    author  = {Li, Ming and Wang, Qiang},
    title   = {The most important paper of the century},
    journal = {Journal of Nonexistence},
    volume  = {25},
    number  = {4},
    pages   = {250--251},
    year    = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}

%\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\citet{li2020most}, \citep{li2020most}.
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question. The OP has indicated that his/her publisher has a separate formatting requirement which may be violated by the approach suggested above. To meet the publisher's supplemental requirement, I suggest one should proceed as follows:

- Find the file `apacite.sty` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say `apacite-natbibapa-nosort.sty`. (The reason for this choice of name will become apparent soon.)
- Open the file `apacite-natbibapa-nosort.sty` in text editor; the program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- On line 46, change

  ```
  \ProvidesPackage{apacite}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \ProvidesPackage{apacite-natbibapa-nosort}
  ```
- Change all three instances of the string

  ```
  [longnamesfirst,sort]
  ```

  to

  ```
  [longnamesfirst]
  ```

  i.e., delete the 'sort' option. In my copy of the file, the strings occur on lines 998, 1000, and 1002.
- Save the file `apacite-natbibapa-nosort.sty` to the directory that contains your main tex file.
- In your main tex file, be sure to include the instructions

  ```
  \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite-natbibapa-nosort}
  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
  ```

  in the preamble.

Happy BibTeXing.

Comment: Thank you. But doesn't `apacite` use the APA-style instead of the Harvard-style of bibliography? I still need the Harvard style.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I realize another issue: "With the `sort` option, `natbib` sorts citations within the same citation command in the same order as in the reference list, as required by the APA manual (p. 178). Therefore, when `apacite` is loaded with the `natbibapa` option, it loads `natbib` with the `sort` option" (`apacite` package documentation). This `sort` option is in conflict with my publisher's style. Is there some way to avoid it and manually order the citations?

Comment: I think it applies to author-year citation as well - I just tested by adding an additional reference. If I cite the two references in a single `\citet{}` command in the reverse order as appears in the bibliography, `apacite` will force change the order back to that in the bibliography.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could retain it. It does solve part of my problem. Sorry about forgetting to upvote.

Comment: Sorry. I understand that `\citet` multiple references is generally not a good idea, but the issue also persists with `\citep` multiple references (my earlier choice of `\citet` was only to illustrate the forced ordered). My publisher explicitly requires the references cited together to appear in a certain order, so I do need to be able to control it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112847/discussion-between-fang-jing-and-mico).

Comment: @FangJing -- Does the addendum I posted to my answer address your sorting-related concerns?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @tvk can you please share the solution through a MWE.